# how to install and start ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64. I have never programmed before and I am trying to learn linux. somewhere I saw that I can learn linux on ubuntu (to be honest I don't get that even). anyways after installing I can't seem to open the program.. after I open what i installed, it asks where I want to copy the program or something?
please help. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu is not a program it is an OS (like Windows) you must install it to your hard drive, not run it from Windows.

"I saw that I can learn linux on ubuntu (to be honest I don't get that even)"

Linux is a small part of Ubuntu, Linux is not the OS itself but the kernel, so Ubuntu is a Linux based OS (amongst other things), there are many Linux based OS they they just get called `linux`. [See here.](http://distrowatch.com/)

You don't want to `learn Linux`, you don't learn Linux, you learn the OS you are using (Ubuntu) as Linux based distributions can be very different.

I will point you in the right direction, first read [this post on installing Ubuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Then this one on [what Linux is](http://opensource.com/resources/what-is-linux) to help with confusion.

Here is the [Ubuntu manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/)

Finally, what you actually need to learn is `bash` the default Ubuntu shell, [what is bash ?](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/What-is-Bash_003f.html) and [How to learn it](http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/bash/).

Comment: With the different distribution stuff - most of em are the same as the same programs are generally available, also the distowatch site lists the popularity of the website's pages, not how much each distro is used - it is also possible to dual boot linxu with windows or use a virtual machine, but generally before installing it is a good idea to do a backup. Also `bash` is brilliant from the Linux point of view, however if you want to do programs that are easier to work cross-platform it is also a good idea to know about python/C/Java etc.

Comment: Thanks for answers, I appreciate it. I ended up installing wubi, which allows me to choose windows or Ubuntu right after I turn on my computer. After I tried connecting to the internet, but was unable to.. something about me needing to be a superuser .. i 'borrow' the internet from my neighbor, so I don't have the driver and can't connect an ethernet cable. any ideas of how I can connect to the internet?

Comment: Bash sounds good. I am taking an online course to learn more about all linux, not sure where they will take me. excited for the adventure :)

Comment: "something about me needing to be a superuser" Gonna need the exact error to help you here, also, wubi sucks, I highly recommend you do an actual install, you will still get the OS choice but wubi affects performance and may cause more issues.